# Efficient way to get best matching pairs given a similarity-outputting neural network?

Tags: keras

I am trying to come up with a neural network that ranks two short pairs of text (for example, stackexchange title and body).  Following the deep learning cookbook's example, the network would look basically like this:

[image]

So we have our two inputs (title and body), embed them, then calculate the cosine similarity between embeddings.  The inputs of the model would be [title,body], the output is [sim].

Now I'd like the closest matching body for a given title.  I am wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this that doesn't involve iterating over every possible pair of (title,body) and calculating the corresponding similarity?  Because for very large datasets this is just not feasible.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed not very efficient to iterate over every possible data pair. Instead you could use your model to extract all the embeddings of your titles and text bodies and save them in a database (or simply a .npy file). So, you don't use your model to output a similarity score but instead use your model to output an embedding (from your embedding layer).

At inference time you can then use a library for efficient similarity search such as [faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). Given a title you would simply look up its embedding and search in the whole embedding space of all body embeddings to see which ones get the highest score. I have used this approach myself and been able to search 1M vectors in just 100 ms.